# C++ : copy constructor that uses a function with non-const parameters

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, copy-constructor

I need to make a copy constructor for my class `Immagine` like this:

```
Immagine::Immagine(Immagine& i)
{
  ...
}
```

obviusly, when I try to call it, i have something like:
 `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Immagine&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Immagine’` because I would declare it as:

```
Immagine::Immagine(const Immagine& i)
{
  ...
}
```

but I can't do it because, to iniatialize an Immagine member object, I use a function

```
Immagine::Immagine(const Immagine& i)
{
  dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel>& r=i.v; //v is a member of type dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel>
  dlib::assign_image(this->dlib_immagine,r);
}
```

function `dlib::assign_image(dst,src)` is a package-function and copies `src` into `dst` but is declared without `const` at `src` parameter,so if I declare `i` as `const` I get an error ... How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't see you using `i` ...

Comment: You insert a `...something...` blackbox in your example which makes it impossible to deduce anything. I doubt you get an error at `assign_image`. `r` is already a non-const reference.

Comment: are you sure? their source shows `dlib::assign_image()` takes a const `src_img` parameter. http://dlib.net/dlib/image_transforms/assign_image_abstract.h.html#assign_image or are you using some older version

Comment: I have corrected my question. sorry

Comment: ok, so what about `const dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel>& r = i.v;` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you can't change `dlib::assign_image()` to take a `const Immagine`, and you are sure that it won't actually change anything, then I would use a [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to remove the const-ness from `i`.

In general it is best to not use `const_cast` if you have another option, but IMO `const_cast` is best used when calling legacy code that isn't const correct, but your code is.

Comment: @volperossa I haven't tried it, but I assume it would work with references as well. I can see it not working with instances though (since that would cause an object copy).